# apache2: unrecognized service in ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04

i try to install Apache 2 on my Ubuntu system version is 14.04 LTS,
installation was success full but when i try to restart the Apache its showing unrecognized service , please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

To start the apache server, you can use this command:

```
$ sudo service httpd start
```

Other available commands are as follows:

```
$ sudo service httpd restart  ## restart the apache server
$ sudo service httpd stop     ## stop the server
```

To list all httpd commands:

```
$ sudo service httpd
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils`

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall apache2 apache2-utils`

`sudo service apache2 start`

and then check by:

`sudo service apache2 status`

Comment: I had a previous version installed which I messed up and couldn't fix it with "normal" uninstall and install, since some files weren't reset. This method, however, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem and solved it by running the following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge  apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install  apache2 apache2-utils apache2.2-bin
```